# Saving Arrays with Multiple File Names in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file

For my project, I am attaining different data for an array with a varying size (I may potentially make it an array list so that new space can be allocated dynamically). The goal I have in mind is to be able to save the array's contents to a new file with each run with a different name. I have seen different methods of writing the contents of an array to a file but in the folder it is being saved to, I assume the name will only change by having a different number on the end of it as Windows doesn't allow multiple files to be saved in the same directory under the same name.

Are there any suggestions anyone has to go about naming the file differently with each run of my program? I don't have a set criteria for how to do it but want to see methods or ways I can do this in Java.

In addition, where are the files typically saved with each run and how can I designate where to save the files to? Would that be as simple as adding the directory name at the beginning of the name of the file separated by a /?

Comment: both questions are way too broad for this site. but for your main question, why not just use a timestamp?

Comment: For saving data, search for “Java serialization”.  As for where to save files, you probably want to start with `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

Comment: What do you mean by timestamp exactly? And I just want to be able to save the names of the files to different names automatically rather than manually if that is possible?

Comment: I found another topic on Stack that actually has an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661092/create-new-file-name-using-variables-in-the-name